# how to check digits present in javascript string or not

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a `regex` which check the string contains only `A-Z`, `a-z` and `special characters` but `not digits` i.e. (`0-9`).
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with this regex:

```
^[^\d]*$
```

And sample:

```
var str = 'test123';
if ( str.match(/^[^\d]*$/) ) {
  alert('matches');
}
```

Comment: Also `^\d` equals `\D` so you can use: `^\D*$`

Comment: thanks for additional info, it works for me so upvote it.i didn't check for other answers as of now so will accept only after checking all the answers

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
/^\D*$/
```

It means, any number of not-a-digit characters. [See it in action…](http://rubular.com/r/sEMfOE12hC)

The alternative is to reverse your test. Just check if there's a digit present, using the trivial:

```
/\d/
```

…and if that matches, your string fails.

Comment: The second regex should be slightly more efficient and is as far as I can tell the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a character class: `^[A-Za-z.,!@#$%^&*()=+_-]+$`.

The `^` and `$` anchor the regex by marching the beginning and end of the string, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
var re = /^[a-zA-Z!#$%]+$/;
```

Fell free to add any special character you need inside the character class